# add class to parent ul on sub item click javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to keep my menu open when a sub item with link is open. I have same class name for the parent menu and sub item link. I need the corresponding menu to remain open when sub item is clicked

thank you

here is what I have try so far

```
 <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link collapsed" data-bs-target="#econ-nav" data-bs- 
                 toggle="collapse" href="#">
                <i class="bi bi-bar-chart"></i><span>finance</span><i 
                     class="bi bi-chevron-down ms-auto"></i>
            </a>
       <ul id="econ-nav" class="nav-content collapse " data-bs-parent="#sidebar-nav">
                                      
                <li>
                    <a class="sub" href="submeni1.html">
                        <i class=" bi bi-circle"></i><span>SubMenu1</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="sub" href="submenu2.html">
                        <i class="bi bi-circle"></i><span>submenu2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                
            </ul>
        </li>

     <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link collapsed" data-bs-target="#econ-nav" data-bs- 
                 toggle="collapse" href="#">
                <i class="bi bi-bar-chart"></i><span>Expenses</span><i 
                     class="bi bi-chevron-down ms-auto"></i>
            </a>
       <ul id="econ-nav" class="nav-content collapse " data-bs-parent="#sidebar-nav">
                                      
                <li>
                    <a class="sub" href="submeni1.html">
                        <i class=" bi bi-circle"></i><span>SubMenu1</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="sub" href="submenu2.html">
                        <i class="bi bi-circle"></i><span>submenu2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                
            </ul>
        </li>
```

and js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.sub').click(function () {

            $(this).parent('nav-content collapse > ul').addClass('show');

         
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.parent()` on an element it gives you the immediate parent of that specific element.

In your case it will be the `<li>` element above the anchor elements. If you want to access `<ul>` element, you will have to get the parent of the `<li>` element.

You can do this by calling `.parent()` again on the element returned by `.parent()`.

```
$(this).parent().parent().addClass('show');
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! it didn't work. Do I need to declare the parent() with the class inside it? thank you

Comment: Try logging the output of $(this).parent().parent() to see if its identifying the correct element. Maybe its something to do with the css class used.

Answer (score 0):

To find a specific element in jquery if they have many levels
use

`$(target_element).closest()` to find parent level or
`$(target_element).find()` to find children level.

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/closest/
Ref: https://api.jquery.com/find/

Hope this might help you.